# Can you use reflection to find out the type of the object on which the current method is executing?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know how to get the current method (`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`).

However, the `DeclaringType` property of `MethodBase` will give me the type on which the method is defined.

I am interested in the type of the method on which it was actually called at runtime.

Comment: Do you mean the type of `this` or the type of the reference on which the method was invoked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the type of the object itself then just use `this.GetType()`?  That will give you the type of `this` on which the current method is executing.

If you mean the type of the reference on which the method was executed then that's not really possible to determine.  Consider virtual methods as an example.

```
abstract class Animal {
  public abstract void MakeNoise();
}
abstract class Dog : Animal { }
class Labrador : Dog {
  public override void MakeNoise() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The reference type could be `Animal` but if the object is `Labrador` then that version of the `MakeNoise` method will be invoked.  Their is no way from the `MakeNoise` method to know if it' was invoked from an `Animal`, `Dog` or `Labrador` instance.